# How to indent/beautify dynamically generated HTML?

Tags: php, html

I combined HTML with PHP to generate a web page. My PHP code is:

```
public function generateSelect()
{
    $data = "<select>\n";

    for ($i = 2000;$i<=2012;$i++)
    {
        $data .= "\t<option value='$i'>$i</option>\n";
    }
    $data .= "</select>";
    $this->data = $data;
    return $this;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <?= $data ?>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

```
<div>
    <select>
    <option value='2000'>2000</option>
    <option value='2001'>2001</option>
    <option value='2002'>2002</option>
    <option value='2003'>2003</option>
    <option value='2004'>2004</option>
    <option value='2005'>2005</option>
    <option value='2006'>2006</option>
    <option value='2007'>2007</option>
    <option value='2008'>2008</option>
    <option value='2009'>2009</option>
    <option value='2010'>2010</option>
    <option value='2011'>2011</option>
    <option value='2012'>2012</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I know that it can be fixed with `\t` and `\n`. But I want to know if there is any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done with PHP's **[`tidy`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)** class. As well as PHP's **[`DOM`](http://il.php.net/dom)** extension.

```
<?php

    $html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <select>
        <option value='2000'>2000</option>
        <option value='2001'>2001</option>
        <option value='2002'>2002</option>
        <option value='2003'>2003</option>
        <option value='2004'>2004</option>
        <option value='2005'>2005</option>
        <option value='2006'>2006</option>
        <option value='2007'>2007</option>
        <option value='2008'>2008</option>
        <option value='2009'>2009</option>
        <option value='2010'>2010</option>
        <option value='2011'>2011</option>
        <option value='2012'>2012</option>
    </select>
</div>
HTML;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($html);

    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: `DOMDocument` works on fragments. So long as they are valid, it should format the code.

Comment: So, I just unindented one of your `option` tags and `DOMDocument` didn't re-indented it. See http://codepad.org/o6vrVkcj.

Answer (score 1):

Like ceejayoz said, it's not necessary, but if you want to do it without \t and \n:

```
for ($i = 2000;$i<=2012;$i++)
{
    $data .= "
    <option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Unfortunately can't revoke unless your comment is edited, so maybe add a line, i revoke, and you revoke your changes.

Comment: So did I. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com no worries!

Comment: When an option's `value` attribute value is identical to the option's text value, then the `value` declaration can be safely removed.  All form submissions and javascript will still work in the same manner without bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Do not be bothered about the markup indentation in the production environment. Do not use HTML beautifiers-filters to hide the underlying issues with the code.

If you need to indent your code in the development environment, beware that earlier mentioned libraries (Tidy and DOM) will attempt to fix your markup (that's their primary purpose; indentation is a by-product).

My [Dindent](https://github.com/gajus/dindent) HTML beautifier will not attempt to sanitise or otherwise manipulate your output beyond indentation. This library is designed to make debugging easier. Do not use it in production.

```
$parser = new \Gajus\Dindent\Parser();
$output = $parser->indent('<p>Your HTML</p>');
```